# Sending multiple html files to a web client with HttpLuaModule‎

Tags: nginx, lua

When I run this script, only the header is displayed:

```
ngx.exec('/header.html')
ngx.exec('/footer.html')
```

What's the best way to serve my template?

I've also tried this:

```
local f = io.read('/header.html','r')
ngx.print(f)
```

but I can't seem to get past a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is not very clear, but

`ngx.exec()` allows you to access a location with args.
If you want to show the html file, you can write a `lua` script and use the `content_by_lua_file` command.

Nginx config:

```
locaction /test {
    default_type "text/plain";
    content_by_lua_file "x.lua";
}
```

Lua Script:

```
local ngx = require 'ngx'
local f = io.open('header.html', 'r')
local html_text = f:read()
ngx.print(html_text)
```

You can access `127.0.0.1/test` through the nginx server
and see your html file now.

Comment: I also think the ngx.say() is better than ngx.print().